# Iframe click not working in Chrome

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
public void nmb_message() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    WebDriver driver = Driverfactory.open("chrome", ".com");
    Logins login = new Logins();
    login.campaignqa();
    String actualTitle = driver.getTitle();
    String expectedTitle = "SmartFocus";

 
    (new Actions(driver)).dragAndDrop(element2, target2).perform();
    WebElement myDynamicElement2 = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
            .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath( "//*[contains(text(), 'Add a picture')]")));
    myDynamicElement2.click();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#msg-editor-imagelib-iframe")));
    Thread.sleep(5000); 
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='item-39571']/div/div[2]")).click(); Thread.sleep(15000L); driver.findElement(By.xpath( "//iframe[@class=contains(text(), 'Apply & close)]")).click(); }}
```

I am already able to switch to iframe , then click on image selection [shown in image 1] and then cannot able to click on div-preview button [shown in image 2 - blue button] which is " apply & close" .

## using the  ""driver.findElement(By.xpath( "//iframe[@class=contains(text(), 'Apply & close)]")).click();" or using Id or css selector.

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

Any idea ?

```html
<div id="msg-editor-imagelib" class="popup-container" style="visibility: visible; opacity: 1;">
<div class="popup-mask"></div>
<div class="popup confirm restrict">
<div class="popup-header">
<span class="popup-header-title left">Add image</span>
<span class="popup-header-close"></span>
</div>
<div class="popup-content">
<div class="switch-container">
<div class="image-popup-content">
</div>
<div class="options-panel-overlay open"></div>
<div class="options-panel-container empty open">
<div class="border-right"></div>
<div class="img-container">
<div class="notification info">You can select an image either by selecting an image from Smartfocus Image Library or enter a distant URL. Once selected, this panel will give you details like ALT tags and link.</div>
</div>
<div class="options-panel-container edition visible open">
<div class="border-right"></div>
<div class="image-preview-container">
<div class="custom-image-preview-placeholder onthefly-placeholder onthefly-placeholder--imghelper hidden">
<img id="image-popup-image-preview" src="http://p2itgtre.emv2.com/IL/5/4/8/1101011548/1735085964.jpg">
</div>
<div class="inputs-block">
<span class="image-label">1735085964</span>
<div id="image-source" class="input-header">
<span>Source</span>
<span class="source">Image Library</span>
</div>
<div class="input-header">
<span>Alternative tag</span>
</div>
<input id="alt-tag-input" type="text" value="">
<div id="alt-tag-helper" class="icon help cue sf-icon sf-icon--small"></div>
</div>
<div class="button-container">
<div id="image-popup-options-apply" class="submit blue popup-confirm">Apply & close</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: could you add relevant html

Comment: just added in image above

Comment: please add HTML text instead of image

Comment: added in post. thanks

Comment: @user4986774 Please share Exception details, if you are getting it

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id='image-popup-options-apply']"}
  
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.36.540470 (e522d04694c7ebea4ba8821272dbef4f9b818c91),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64) 
version=67.0.3396.87, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, locationContextEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: e4e1e7dfedd7cf83f04ef80812354dbd
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=.//*[@id='image-popup-options-apply']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this Xpath for Apply and close

```
.//*[@id='image-popup-options-apply']
```

Comment: Thanks but the xpath is not working and showing error no such element .

Comment: are you using this xpath after switching to frame ?

Comment: I am using " driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='item-39571']/div/div[2]")).click();"  after switching frame . After that I am using xpath you mentioned here ".//*[@id='image-popup-options-apply']" but cannot able to click on the Apply and close button in Iframe or diversion

Comment: what does id='item-39571 contain, I can't find this id in your HTML

Comment: its picture 1735085964 mentioned in HTML. But that is item number 39571 in database . When we click on the picture an div popup appears (shown in image -2 above). Need to close the div popup and iframe so the picture can be inserted in parent frame

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id='image-popup-options-apply']"} (Driver info: chromedriver=2.36.540470 (e522d04694c7ebea4ba8821272dbef4f9b818c91),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64) version=67.0.3396.87, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, locationContextEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}] Session ID: e4e1e7dfedd7cf83f04ef80812354dbd *** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=.//*[@id='image-popup-options-apply']

Comment: I think in that case you need to change back to your parent frame

Comment: yes thanks as I need to go back to parent frame and the above xpath is working once I am in parent frame.